# Checkbox grid alignment inside well for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to get my checkboxes to align with the labels and select options inside a well using bootstrap 3.3.5. My code is:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Checkboxes</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="1">1
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="2">2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Select</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="2" class="form_control">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle illustrating misalignment:

https://jsfiddle.net/dwzvsoax/

I'm pretty new to bootstrap, so I'm probably doing something dumb! Thank you in advance.

Comment: to accept an answer, hover beside the answer in question and click the tick that appears beside it. It means 15 points for the answerer and you get a badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your form elements and labels together with a `.form-group` element.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hz4w2n3m/)

Also, you should read the [Boostrap Documentation on Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Check Boxes</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" /> 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" /> 2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>select</label>
        <select id="2" class="form-control">
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was easy... I figured it was something simple.

Comment: Thanks! Previously I was add `checkbox` class in label.

Answer (score 0):

you could add in to the `.checkbox` class an attribute `margin-left:22px;` in the css file and that should give you the desired effect. If it's just on one page though, just add it in style tags at the top of the page, as it may not be desirable everywhere.

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwzvsoax/2/)